# Just want to double-check my answer to a volume bounded by a plane and a surface

Tags: definite-integrals

Can someone please spend a couple minutes in checking my answer, it will be much appreciated

**Question**

Find the finite volume bounded by $y=1-x^2-4z^2$ and $y=0$.

**My answer**

The answer I got was $\frac{\pi}{4}$. If there is a difference between my answer and yours then I will share my workings!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your answer is correct. [Here](https://www.symbolab.com/solver/double-integrals-calculator) is an online calculator to check your answer in future.